# Server tag is not well formed error on GridView row LinkButton

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm getting this error and I can't for the life of me figure out why.  Basically, I've got a LinkButton on each row of a GridView control that should delete the record associated with that row when clicked.  I've used the Container.DataItem before successfully with hrefs, but haven't tried before with a LinkButton.  The link should pass the GridView's DataKey to a server-side function that deletes the record from the database.  Any help is greatly appreciated!  Here is the relevant code:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDeleteInfoRequest" runat="server" onClick="DeleteInfoRequest(this, <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pKey") %>)" Text="Delete?" />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Try to wrap `onClick` in single quotes `onClick='DeleteInfoRequest(this, <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pKey") %>)'`

Comment: Thanks for the lightning-fast response!  I had tried that before and got the following error:
XML literal cannot appear here unless it is enclosed in parentheses

Comment: Maybe try this `onClick='<%# "DeleteInfoRequest(this," +   DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pKey") + ");" %>)'`

Comment: Thanks again, I really appreciate the feedback!  That gave the following error:
XML elements cannot be selected from type 'ASP.casedetail_aspx'.

Comment: Are you trying to make a call to `javascript` function `DeleteInfoRequest` on `LinkButton` click ?

Comment: No, I know to use OnClientClick in that case.  I'm trying to pass the gridview row's datakey to a server-side function.

Comment: Oh, my bad I thought you're trying to make a call to `javascript` funtion. Then the best option is to follow the code in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your aspx code like this:

```
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDeleteInfoRequest" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("pKey")%>' OnClick="DeleteInfoRequest" Text="Delete?" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

And create code behind like this:

```
Protected Sub DeleteInfoRequest(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim btnDeleteInfoRequest As LinkButton = TryCast(sender, LinkButton)
    Dim pKey As String = btnDeleteInfoRequest.CommandArgument

    'TODO: do your stuff here
End Sub
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Gregor, that worked beautifully!  Thanks so much!  I haven't used CommandArgument before in this context.